# Validating XML in Python without non-python dependencies

Tags: python, xml, validation, schema, dtd

I'm writing a small Python app for distribution. I need to include simple XML validation (it's a debugging tool), but I want to avoid any dependencies on compiled C libraries such as lxml or pyxml as those will make the resulting app much harder to distribute. I can't find anything that seems to fit the bill - for DTDs, Relax NG or XML Schema. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like [MiniXsv](http://www.familieleuthe.de/MiniXsv.html)? I have never used it, but from the website, we can read that

> minixsv is a lightweight XML schema
>   validator package written in pure
>   Python (at least Python 2.4 is
>   required).

so, it should work for you.

I believe that [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) could also be used for that goal, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try invoking an online XML validator and parsing the results?

I couldn't find any free REST or SOAP based services but it would be easy enough to use a normal HTML form based one such as [this one](http://www.stg.brown.edu/service/xmlvalid/) or [this one](http://www.validome.org/xml/).  You just need to construct the correct request and parse the results ([httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) may be of help here if you don't want to use a third party library such as [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to easy the pain).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at it in a while so it might have changed, but Fourthought's [4Suite](http://www.fourthought.com/4Suite.html) ([community edition](http://4suite.org/index.xhtml)) could still be pure Python.

Edit: just browsed through the docs and it's **mostly** Python which probably isn't enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

The beautifulsoup module is pure Python (and a single .py file), but I don't know if it will fulfill your validation needs, I've only used it for quickly extracting some fields on large XMLs.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/